# What kind of access control mechanism is supported in YugaByte DB?

Tags: database, yugabytedb

What kind of access control mechanism (user/roles & grant, revoke, etc.) do the YugaByte APIs support, and if so which release of YugaByte includes this support?

Answer (score 0):

The response below is applicable as of YugaByte DB release 1.1.7.

YugaByte DB's YCQL API supports role based access control similar to Apache Cassandra.

For example:

```
CREATE ROLE IF NOT EXISTS engineering;
CREATE ROLE IF NOT EXISTS john WITH PASSWORD = 'PasswdForJohn' AND LOGIN = true;
GRANT engineering TO john;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL KEYSPACES TO engineering;
```

The YugaByte's YEDIS API (persistent, elastic Redis-like API) supports a password based authentication scheme. You can enable access control to enforce password based authentication in YEDIS using the CONFIG command.

```
CONFIG SET requirepass "password"
```

Note that YEDIS also allows for multiple passwords (currently up to 2) to be accepted. This enables performing a graceful change/rolling upgrades of the password without experiencing any application outage.

YugaByte's SQL API's role based access control (currently in development) will be similar to that of Postgres.

For more details see: https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/secure/.